# Name of the inequality $ a \ge b $ vs. $a \le b$

Tags: terminology

Suppose that you have an inequality
$$ a \le b \tag{I}.$$ Does in English the inequality $$ a \ge b $$ has a special name? Can we say that it is the *converse* or *reciprocal* inequality vs. $(I)$?

Comment: Like; *Greater than or equal to* and *Less than or equal to*?

Comment: I'd call it the *converse* relation.

Comment: As it isn't really the converse, I wouldn't call it the converse inequality.

Comment: I've seen this called the "reverse" inequality. I would never call it the "converse" inequality (that would be something like "$\lnot (a>b)$", wouldn't it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually hear the *converse* relation.

Though be careful, that is not really a standard terminology, and it is better to actually say what you mean, *i.e.* here : $a$ is greater or equal than $b$.

Comment: You'll even find that term [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Converse) in a familiar tertiary reference where it was first added in March 2012.  The related idea "reverse" was present at various times prior to 2009 ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inequality_(mathematics)&oldid=240776378) ).